# Angular 2 - Update directive when change window size

Tags: angular, frontend

I have directive (custom *ngIf) that should hide element when width of window more 700px. When i change window size my derective is not update and element not hided but `this.width` update always. Have some idea how it could fix? Here is example:

```html
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, HostListener,NgZone} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ifViewportSize]'
})

export class ifViewportSize {
  width:number;

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, 
  private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,  
  private ngZone:NgZone) {
    this.width = 600;

    window.onresize = (e) => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.width = window.innerWidth; // WIDTH UPDATING
      });
    };
  }

  @Input() set ifViewportSize(size: string){
    if (this.width<700) { 
      
     // HERE IS NOT UPDATE

      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }

  }
  
}
```

Project code is here [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xc8zhw?file=app%2FifViewportSize.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using *ngIf this can help you:

In the constructor:

```
constructor(private element: ElementRef /*other dependencies*/) {
   // your code here
}
```

Outside of the constructor use this:

```
@HostListener('window:resize', [])
onWindowResize(): void {
    if (window.innerWidth < 700) {
        this.element.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        this.element.nativeElement.style.display = 'block';
    };
}
```

To import HostListener and ElementRef:

```
import {ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
```

I hope this helps you.